# Does a long running network call in php tie up a processor core?

Tags: php, laravel, redis

So I have an application that in response to practically any user action needs to call out to a third party system. Said 3rd party system is horrendously slow (400-500ms network response times).

So, to keep user actions fast instead of making the call immediately a job is queued in a Redis cache, and a cluster of queue workers pick up on these jobs and actually make the calls to the 3rd party service.

What I'm noticing though is that after pushing these jobs into the queue the CPU utilization for the queue workers has spiked dramatically. A colleague of mine suggests it's not due to the new job types (at least, not in the way I'm thinking) because the CPU cores of the workers will jump to another process while a given process is occupied with a long running network call.

My question is-- does it? With PHP, if I make a long running network call, is the CPU core occupied waiting for that call? How can I test if this is the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set-up a 'slow server' `index.php`:

```
<?php
sleep(10);
echo 'OK';
```

and a client `client.php`:

```
<?php
echo "GOT: ".file_get_contents('http://localhost:8081')."\n";
```

In a terminal, start the PHP built-in webserver in the directory containing `index.php`

```
$ php -S localhost:8081 &
```

(The trailing ampersand to have it run in BG)
And then run and time the client:

```
$ time php -f client.php
```

Which leaves you with

```
[Wed Apr 18 09:00:00 2018] ::1:12345 [200]: /
GOT: OK
php -f client.php 0.05s user 0.01s system 0% cpu 10.070 total
```

So, no significant user or system time. Only waiting (which allows other processes to run)

Comparing that to a script that actually does things:

`$ time php -f pi.php`

`9.49s user 0.02s system 99% cpu 9.530 total`